# Revit 2021 viewer in WPF application

Tags: autodesk-viewer, revit-api, autodesk

I'm looking to integrate revit viewer in wpf C# application.
Any reference with example will help.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know Revit doesn't support embedding. A couple of ideas on how to approach this:

a) Upload your model to [APS](https://aps.autodesk.com/) and embed their viewer using WebView2 or CefSharp.

b) Export your Revit models to a format which can be rendered natively in your app, eg. IFC, glTF, FBX etc.

c) Check out the [BimRv SDK](https://www.opendesign.com/products/bimrv)